# i am trying to update the DATA but this query work with insert

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

```
Query quer = sess.createQuery("update materialrate  set materialId=:MaterialId, subWorkId=:SubWorkId,unitId=:UnitId ,rate=:Rate, lastUpdatedUserId=:LastUpdatedUserId  where materialRateId=:MaterialRateId");
 quer.setInteger("materialId", n.getMaterialId());
        quer.setInteger("subWorkId", n.getSubWorkId());
        quer.setInteger("unitId", n.getUnitId());
        quer.setInteger("rate",n.getRate());
       // quer.setDate("lastUpdatedDate", current_timestamp());//lastUpdateDate=:current_timestamp() ,
        quer.setInteger("lastUpdatedUserId", n.getLastUpdatedUserId());
        quer.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Named Parameters you need to use same name while setting the values of these.Replace your code with the following line:

```
Query quer = sess.createQuery("update materialrate  set materialId=:MaterialId, subWorkId=:SubWorkId,unitId=:UnitId ,rate=:Rate, lastUpdatedUserId=:LastUpdatedUserId  where materialRateId=:MaterialRateId");
 quer.setInteger("MaterialId", n.getMaterialId());
        quer.setInteger("SubWorkId", n.getSubWorkId());
        quer.setInteger("UnitId ", n.getUnitId());
        quer.setInteger("Rate",n.getRate());
       // quer.setDate("lastUpdatedDate", current_timestamp());//lastUpdateDate=:current_timestamp() ,
        quer.setInteger("LastUpdatedUserId ", n.getLastUpdatedUserId());
        quer.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thanks to post but it not working . you have any hibernate code for date auto generater

Comment: what is not working?...and What do you mean by date auto generator that is out of scope for this question...